# Change Custom Post Type singular_name through function/filter

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I'm working on e-commerce site using woocommerce plugin. My client will be selling tickets online. woocommerce plugin creates custom post type "Product".

I want to change this cpt singular_name to "Ticket" (just a cosmetic change)

I'm ok with keeping cpt slug to "product" as it requires for other woocommerce functions?

[image: cpt_product]

Is there any function/filter available in wordpress to alter custom post type singular_name through function/filter

Comment: WooCommerce provides a large range of hooks and filters which you can use. Its a plugin specific question and not really specific to WordPress.http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

Comment: OK Thanks. I will have a look. But in general, is there any way to alter it outside any plugin ? not woocommerce only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the source of `register_post_type`, you'll see that it uses [`get_post_type_labels()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_type_labels/). And this function has a filter:

```
apply_filters( "post_type_labels_{$post_type}", $labels );
```

Better use that instead of messing with the actual arguments.

Comment: And here's an example https://gist.github.com/markoheijnen/2399864

Comment: @BradDalton As an [edit] please (even better with the code instead of the link ;) )